# How do you get saddles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I get a saddle for my horse?

Is it a crafted item, or a looted item?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to craft one with leather.

Comment: I'll post an answer, but you should research online and try to find an answer before asking here.

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Saddle

Comment: @Thom, Horse saddles can be crafted before version 1.6.1. In that version, horse saddles were removed and replaced with plain old saddles. Saddles cannot be crafted, and you can use them on pigs and horses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to obtain a saddle.

From the [Minecraft Wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Saddle):

> **Natural Generation** - Saddles can be found in chests inside dungeons, abandoned mine shafts, Nether fortresses, desert temples, jungle temples, and in blacksmith chests in villages.

> **Fishing** - Saddles can be obtained as a "treasure" item from fishing.

> **Trading** - Villager leatherworkers will sell saddles for 8-10 emeralds as a third tier trade.

As of version 1.6.1, saddles cannot be crafted. Good luck!